# obtain data using columns data indices

Tags: matlab

i have data A=( 3,5,3,1,4 ) in a column and

```
B=[ 
 4   6   9  1   3
 2   7   2  5   7
 7   3   1  8   2
 4   1   6  9   1
 2   5   8  3   6 ]
```

And i want: as in A first element is 3 and for this i want to get first element of column 3 row 1 from B which is 9. The second element of A is 5 and for this i want to get the the 2nd element  of column 5 and row 2 from B which is 7 ,and do the process for all other elements . how to do this in matlab? the required elements are bold and underlined. The desired output is `[9,7,1,4,3]`

Comment: Your question originally asked, *how to do this in matalb?*  I assumed you meant [tag:matlab] and edited the question accordingly.  Please feel free to roll back my change if I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Read about linear indexes.

sub2ind will convert from [row col] to index.

```
Cols=[ 3,5,3,1,4 ];
Rows=1:length(Cols);

B=[ 
 4   6   9  1   3
 2   7   2  5   7
 7   3   1  8   2
 4   1   6  9   1
 2   5   8  3   6 ];

Indexes=sub2ind(size(B),Rows,Cols);
Vals=B(Indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

if I've read well you want an elements replacement. It's quite simple 
`A(1)=B(1,3)
A(2)=B(2,5)`

So after you have declared your two vectors you can handle them replacing singular components. In general when you have a 1-D vectors you can access to it's component position only declaring the position itself inside the parentheses, as I did for A.
Whe you have to face situation like in B, If you remember linear algebra and matrix in general B(a,b) means the element of matrix B placed in the line a and column b so you have to specify row and column to access that element.